# Minecraft redstone questions about computers, here or in another page?

Tags: discussion

In Minecraft, exists the possibility to use redstone and then use it in redstone contraptions, such as computers. However, minecraft-related questions goes here (Arqade), but computer designing goes in another site.

Yesterday I wanted to post a question about redstone (that's about designing a CPU), but I was'nt sure about where to post it.

Can someone clarify this doubt? Any help is higly appreciated.

Comment: It would probably depend on the question; asking how to layout the redstone to perform [function]? that would be fine here. Asking how CPUs perform [function]? not a good fit for arqade.